# SELinux: 'chcon' is not reflected in another user account

Tags: selinux

I am using Debian 6 with SELinux enabled.

For testing, I have tried to block access to `date` command for users. Now, I have mapped 'Test_Unix_User' account to 'user_u' SELinux account.

'user_r' can execute all commands that have role-set 'object_r'. So, I decided to change role-set from 'object_r' to 'sysadm_r'.

Before changing role-set,
output of `ls -Z /bin/date` : "`system_u:object_r:bin_t /bin/date`"
After changing role-set,
output of `ls -Z /bin/date` : "`system_u:sysadm_r:bin_t /bin/date`"

All seems fine. But, When I logged in to 'Test_Unix_User' account, then listing `/bin/date` with security contexts, shows me different file context.

Output of `ls -Z /bin/date` in 'Test_Unix_User' account is,
"`system_u:object_r:bin_t /bin/date`"

Why changing file context in root, is not reflecting in user account?? Is file context tend to be changed for every login account??
Since, file context is not changed, I can't block access to 'date' command.
I am trying to give access to users to execute some commands, but not all.